# Rails store and retrieve time only in the following format: hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time, model

I generated my model like this:

```
class CreateMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_model do |t|
      t.references :place, index: true
      t.time :time_first
      t.time :time_second

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Saving the model to mysql works fine. The time columns are populated as hh:mm:ss, which is fine. But when I retrieve the entries from mysql, somehow it includes the date from 2000-01-01, example:

```
2000-01-01T17:00:00Z
```

How can I retrieve the time columns as hh:mm:ss?

I'm querying the table entry like this:

```
my_model = MyModel.find(id)
print my_model.to_json#here time_first and time_second include date.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for time in mint and hours:

`my_model.time_second.strftime("%H:%M %S %p")`

Comment: So if I have an array of my_model, I have to iterate through each entry to format the time before I can render it? The time is already saved in the right format, so this seems like unnecessary overhead to me.

Comment: write a helper method that used _strftime()_ function and call when you have retrieved the entries from mysql, it 'll help you to avoid iterate each entry to format it before render it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no time-only data type in ruby, so even though you save it to your db as time-only column, it will always be parsed back as a date with time (defaulting to 2000 Jan 1st). You can define an attribute reader though to convert the parsed datetime to your preferred format, e.g. a "HH:MM:SS" string or today's time:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  # this will return the time formatted as a string:
  def time_first
    read_attribute(:time_first).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end

  # or
  # this will return the time as todays datetime object:
  def time_first
    Time.parse(read_attribute(:time_first).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
  end

end
```

Choose one of the approaches that suits your needs best.